# What are the length of the longest element in a Coexter group for every type?

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups

What are the length of the longest element in a Coxeter group for every type? Thank you very much.

Comment: Good question. I thought this would be fast and easy to look up (surely someone has calculated it), but I could not find it (I didn't check Bourbaki though, where it almost certainly must be).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The length of the longest element is exactly the number of positive roots, so

- Type $A_n$: ${n + 1} \choose 2$
- Types $B_n, C_n$: $n^2$
- Type $D_n$: $n^2 - n$
- Type $I_2(n)$: n
- Type $E_6$: 36
- Type $E_7$: 63
- Type $E_8$: 120
- Type $F_4$: 24
- Type $G_2$: 6
- Type $H_3$: 15
- Type $H_4$: 60

Comment: thank you very much. How to show that the length is the number of positive roots?

Comment: @LJR: This is one definition of the length function -- $l(w)$ is the number of positive roots $\alpha$ such that $w(\alpha)$ is a negative root.  Then you simply need to know that there exists an element of $W$ that sends all positive roots to negative roots, and this is proven using the fact that if $w$ does not send $\alpha$ to a negative root, then $w s_{\alpha}$ does and moreover $w s_{\alpha}$ sends the same number of positive roots besides $\alpha$ to negative roots as $w$ does.  Thus $w s_{\alpha}$ sends one more positive root to a negative root than $w$ does.

Comment: @LJR: In general the length of an element of the Coxeter group is always equal to the number of positive roots that it sends to negative roots.  It's corollary 1.7 in [Humphrey's Coxeter groups](http://books.google.com/books?id=ODfjmOeNLMUC&lpg=PA13&vq=deletion%20condition&pg=PA14#v=onepage&q&f=false) book, $n(w)$ is the number of positive roots $w$ sends to negative roots and $\ell(w)$ is the minimal length of $w$ as a word.  In 1.8 of the same you prove that $W$ acts simply transitively on bases, so the longest element must be the one that takes the base $\Delta$ to $-\Delta$.

Comment: @MichaelJoyce, thank you very much.

Comment: @Jim, thank you very much.